# href - append a parameter to current url without javascript

Tags: html, href

My webpage url looks like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/show-index/index?limit=100
```

Where limit defines the number of items to display.
I'd like to add a 'show more' which would basically add 'more=true' to my current url:

```
http://mywebsite.com/show-index/index?limit=100&more=true
```

I've tried this:

```
href='?more=true'
```

But it overides the parameter limit.

Is there a simple way to do it without using javscript?
Thanks

Comment: use `href="?limit=100&more=true"`

Comment: If you don't want to reaload the page i don't think.
The best way would be to handle that with ajax ...

If you want to reload the page : <a href="http://mywebsite.com/show-index/index?limit=100&more=true">Show more</a>

Comment: What keeps you from using a simple anchor tag pointing to that address with that extra parameter ?

Comment: yes but my limit will change when I first click on 'show more' so it won't work the second time I click on it :(

Comment: why not ? if you detect that more=true so just change limit to limit+100

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to do it by Ajax.

If you really don't want to, just use a link
`<a href="http://mywebsite.com/show-index/index?limit=100&more=true"</a>`

On PHP side, if you detect `$_GET['more']='true'`, juste change the limit to limit+100 in the link.

The best would be to add some achor as @Bartdude says to do not have to scroll each time the page is reloaded.

Don't forget to upvote and mark as solved if you find this useful :)